# Creating a client side Spotify player

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to create a web app that uses Spotify to play tracks. I'm following [this tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/).

I finished the setup and now I don't understand this section: [Listening through the SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/#listening-through-the-sdk)

It says "To play a track inside your browser, connect to the Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player player in another Spotify client". Is it telling me to create a client in my Javascript code? That's what I'm trying to do.  There is no player on the page I've created.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your spotify app on your laptop and play a song, click this button:

[image]

Then choose the option "Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player". Now, if you open your `index.html` in a supported browser, you should hear the music playing.

Helpful link: https://www.spotify.com/us/connect/